# Glassfish: Admin console logs me out before timeout

Tags: glassfish

The glassfish admin console (the web-gui) keeps kicking me out after a quite short amount of time. The default session timeout of 60 minutes wasn't changed. By a short amount of time I'm talking about like 5-10min.

Any idea what might cause this?

I'm connected via localhost without password, but also tried to set a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had an application deployed on root-level-context "/" and everytime this app logged out it also killed my admin-gui-session (which was in another tab open in the same browser).